# The browser opened by geckodriver, is not using default settings for running Robot script

Tags: firefox, robotframework, geckodriver

I've set layout.css.devPixelsPerPx in Firefox to be 0.9 (open a new tab, write "about:config" & hit Enter), since I want the browser to be opened with certain level of zoom aspect. It is working fine, when I'm opening the browser manually.

But when I run a robot script, it opens the browser with zoomed in instead of the one, already set above.

So far I've tried following options, apart from above -
1. Tried using Firefox extension, which set default zoom level, but the browser opened by Geckodriver, doen't have that extension available.
2. Run Cntrl+- to zoom out, but as soon as the url changes, the zoom is reset to 100%
3. I can have the Browser open with a command (which has the correct zoom level set). Is there a way, I can ask Robot to use the existing instance of browser than opening new one?

How can I have the Robot open the Firefox browser with certain level of zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't see the setting effective when you run the script is because Selenium creates a new profile when it starts a browser.

Any changes you do in your browser, any extensions you add, are stored in your user's profile. Selenium uses a clean/vanilla (as in: having the default settings) profile so your testing environment is always clean - not influenced by customizations, extensions, cached resources you may have added in your daily work.

If you want to have a particular setting changed in your *Selenium* browser session, under Firefox with Robotframework - you're "in luck" :). The SeleniumLibrary that comes with it supports starting the browser with a precreted profile - [see the documentation, the Open Browser keyword](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) - it has an argument `ff_profile_dir`.
So create a FF profile with your setting set to the value you need (I don't see a reason why it won't be stored there), and pass its directory as parameter to the `Open Browser` keyword. Thus when Selenium creates a browser instance, it will use this profile, with that setting effective.